# Force to load System.Xml assembly v. 2.0.5.0

Tags: c#, xml, assemblies, load

I have got a problem with missmatching the assemblies - on the server site I need to use System.Xml assembly in version 2.0.5.0. How to force loading this assembly on the client site (2.0.5.0 is a Silverlight assembly).

Comment: Umm ... why would you want to do that?

Comment: What version of the Silverlight SDK are you targeting?

Comment: For debugging reasons, Ive got SL3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Xml is GAC'd, have you referenced the Silverlight specific version of System.Xml? If so (for reasons which are beyond me!) you need to make sure that CopyLocal is set to true for that assembly reference, otherwise it won't get pushed to the output when you build.

Comment: Yup, I have set CopyLocal to true, but without any results. Any idea?

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you need Silverlight's System.Xml on the server, it's a client-side library :S